# Using Geolocation in flex, AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, geolocation

I'm trying to use the geolocation framework in my flex website to determine the position of the user. I researched it and it seems a fairly easy way to do this by using the as3 framework geolocation. But I'm facing the following problem. When instantiating the mxml where i have:

```
import flash.sensors.GeoLocation; (i can use intellisense the complete this!)
private var geoLocation:GeoLocation;
```

It gives an error it cant find the class flash.sensors::Geolocation.
It should be in the playerglobal.swc that can be found under ./Adobe Flash Builder 4.5\sdks\4.5.1\frameworks\libs\player\10.2. I've decompiled this swc and can see in the xml file that the method is there(as you can see below)

```
<script name="flash/sensors/Geolocation" mod="1290556075000"                               signatureChecksum="2317064902" >
    <def id="flash.sensors:Geolocation" /> 
    <dep id="flash.events:EventDispatcher" type="i" /> 
    <dep id="Boolean" type="s" /> 
    <dep id="Number" type="s" /> 
    <dep id="flash.events:GeolocationEvent" type="e" /> 
    <dep id="flash.events:StatusEvent" type="e" /> 
  </script>
```

I've tried adding the library to my project in the flex build path but it doesn't help.
Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
import flash.sensors.Geolocation;
```

Small "**l**" letter.

Comment: Then, ensure, that you're using appropriate SDK (4.5)